# Spark Job Submission on EMR

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

I am having close to 100+ spark jobs to submit. But my cluster can run only maximum 4-5 job at a particular point of time. Can I submit all the jobs in one go? How yarn will behave in this case?
Will it pick jobs as soon as cluster is available? How long jobs can wait? What setting do I need to make?

Note : I am not supposed to enable Auto Scaling feature of EMR.

Comment: you can submit as many jobs as you can.. some will go into RUNNING state and some will be in ACCEPTED state and waiting (in schedular queue) for there turn to come.

Comment: I would say follow up the practices applied here https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/best-practices-for-successfully-managing-memory-for-apache-spark-applications-on-amazon-emr/

Comment: run every job in a way that take all the available resources then run them one by one or run them in a way that two jobs run sequentially